# Display.getRefreshRate() giving me different values in different devices

Tags: android

I'm using Display.getRefreshRate() to retrieve the refresh rate of my display. In an X10 Mini, the value returned is 0.325. In a Galaxy S, the value is 68.0. This doesn't make any sense to me. Any ideas?

Comment: +1 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRefreshRate() states frames per second. Yet my Galaxy Ace is giving me `0.34`. 0.34 frames per second!? I can flip a comic book faster than that rate.

Comment: +1 I discovered the same! My Xperia Pro gives a value <1.0. Imo this is a really sloppy bug on the part of the phone manufacturers!

Comment: Confirming that this is somewhat a bug. For my LG Optimus Chic it returns the value 0.054 which doesn't make any sense. Even if it was the fraction of a second between one frame and the next it would result in 18.5 fps while the manufacturer reports 30 fps for this specific smartphone.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug, though I haven't found any bug reports for it. The number I get out is also ~0.34, while I was expecting something like 60. I havent managed to find a meaningfull interpretation of 0.34 with regard to refreshrates, and so my solution was simply to "reject its truth and substitute my own" with the following code:

```
public float getRefreshRate() {
    final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    final Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    float rate = display.getRefreshRate();
    if (rate < 10.0f) {
        rate = 60.0f; //Default to something which seems to be a normal refreshrate on many phones
    }
    return rate;
}
```

This works great in my app. Hope this was helpfull!